# MySQL: select all with all the listed values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```js
+-------------+
|  id  | cars |
+------|------+
|  45  |   9  |
+------|------+
|  20  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   5  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  20  |   5  |
+------|------+
|  42  |   3  |
+------|------+
|  19  |   5  |
+------|------+
```

I need get table something like this

```js
+-------------+
|  id  | cars |
+------|------+
|  20  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   5  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  20  |   5  |
+------|------+
```

Therefore I need select only those rows that have all equal cars values in list(5, 2). *Oh, and I could not use id column, only cars*

I tried this query

```js
SELECT * FROM myTable where cars in(5, 2)
```

but it returs this table

```js
+-------------+
|  id  | cars |
+------|------+
|  20  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   5  |
+------|------+
|  25  |   2  |
+------|------+
|  20  |   5  |
+------|------+
|  19  |   5  |
+------|------+
```

How select onlnly those rows that have all valaues in list(5, 2)?
Sorry if my question is not very clean

Comment: Why do you need all the rows?  Why not just the two ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient, and it will get really cumbersome with more cars in your list, but this gives the results you're looking for with your sample:

```
select id, cars
from myTable
where id in (
  select id
  from myTable
  where cars = 5
)
and id in (
  select id
  from myTable
  where cars = 2
)
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e251a/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

`in` is an `or`-type matching. ANY records that have one of the values in the `in` list will be found. To change it to an `and` type situation gets much more complicated:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS main
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT id, cars, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM yourtable
   WHERE cars IN (5,2)
   GROUP BY cars
   HAVING cnt = 2
) AS child ON (main.id = child.id) AND (main.cars = child.cars)
```

The subselect figures out which `cars` have both `5` and `2`, then the parent query uses that to retrieve the associated `id` for those particular `cars`.

caveat: not tested, it's been a long day, brain is fried, but the proper answer is somewhere close to this.